# Vue.js callback references rather than emits

Tags: vue.js, callback

In vue.js, to call the functionality of the parents from the childs, I tend to use callback references (passing function references as props) rather than using the emits. I think its more weighted to use emits as the listeners might slow down the page. Is this the proper approach?

Comment: use `Props` for inputs to child and `events` for output from  child. That's a pretty standard approach;

Comment: "listeners might slow down the page"   If this is a genuine concern, you should actually test performance of event listeners compared to callback functions before going with what you clearly already know is not the standard approach in Vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and set up a performance test for you.

### Listeners are significantly faster than callbacks.

Comparison of 10 callbacks/listeners each called 10 times show that callbacks are between 5% and 15% slower than listeners.  The difference in performance increases the more each callback/listener is executed: at 1000 executions callbacks are between 15% and 25% slower.

https://jsperf.com/vuejs-listener-vs-callback/

I'd welcome corrections in case I've made any dumb mistakes that make this an unfair test, but so far it appears that the standard $emit / $on pattern is very much preferable in terms of performance to passing around callback props.

This isn't to say that callbacks should never be used -- they can be more convenient in some cases, and might be a more familiar idiom for developers coming from React.  But don't use vague concerns about performance to justify that preference.

### The test code

Here's the code I compared:

#### Listeners:

For simplicity's sake I used the common event bus pattern here, rather than communicating directly between components; I don't believe that would make a significant difference in performance (but welcome corrections if so!)

```js
var bus = new Vue({});

Vue.component('parent', {
  template: '<div>Parent {{counter}} <child></child></div>',
  data() {return {counter: 0}},
  beforeMount() {
    // 10 listeners
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    window.bus.$on('testemit'+i, () => {
      this.counter++;
    });
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>Child</div>',
  mounted() {
    // call each listener 10 times
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
      for (var j=0; j<10; j++) {
        window.bus.$emit('testemit'+i);
      }
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

#### Callbacks:

For fairness between the tests an event bus instance is set up here as well as in the listener test; it's then ignored in favor of callback props.

```js
var bus = new Vue({});

Vue.component('parent', {
  // 10 callback props
  template: "<div>Parent {{counter}}<child :c1='foo' :c2='foo' :c3='foo' :c4='foo' :c5='foo' :c6='foo' :c7='foo' :c8='foo' :c9='foo' :c10='foo' ></child></div>",
  data() {return {counter: 0}},
  methods: {
    foo() {
      this.counter++
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>Child</div>',
  props: ["c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10"],
  mounted() {
    // call each callback 10 times
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
      this.c1();
      this.c2();
      this.c3();
      this.c4();
      this.c5();
      this.c6();
      this.c7();
      this.c8();
      this.c9();
      this.c10();
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for this comparison. Seems I should consider emit. But a small issue as the emits are totally dynamic names and there can be a chance that calling emit is not defined in a parent, so it won't fire. But if we go for references we can directly for the existence. Do you prefer method references in that context?

Comment: You're *really* searching for a reason to justify your preference for callbacks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be emitting dynamically-named events to parents that aren't prepared to receive those events, that sounds like a really contrived example.

Comment: Personally I don't lean very heavily on the $emit/$on pattern.  Most of the time I handle cross-component communication by not requiring the components to communicate with each other in the first place: have them work from a shared data store, vuex or the like; that way any component can just update the store and every other component using the same bit of data will be able to read it straight from the same source of truth.   $emit/$on tends to be reserved for components that are explicitly tightly bound to each other, so the specific messages to be emitted and received are clearly defined.

Comment: I've never used a callback prop in vue; it's one of the patterns I don't love about React (I think it makes it too easy to create unnecessary interdependence between components.)    Feel free to like what you like; just know you're paying a bit of a performance penalty and doing things in an atypical way for the framework.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for all of these explanations.